# Can I extend attic vents so they don't get blocked by snow?

Tags: roof, vent, attic

I have 2 square low profile attic vents on the detached garage but I'm pretty sure they are blocked with snow during the winter. If I should alter them, are there extensions available to raise these without replacing the vents themselves?

Comment: What kind of venting and insulation do you have in the detached garage roof, if any?

Comment: There is no insulation yet. The vents are low profile. Approximately 4" in overall height. Similar to the following: http://www.homedepot.ca/product/60-nfa-black-roof-louver-high-impact-resin-square-top/935113